# DigitalOcean droplet connection refused on every request

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, digital-ocean

I managed to put my project in the droplet and run docker-compose build successfully. When I run docker-compose up and try to use swagger on my domain I get the following error messages in the console.

```
https-portal1_1 | 2020/03/03 22:52:13 [error] 291#291: *51 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream.
```

I must add that Nginx is not installed because I'm new to this and am in need of some help.

docker-compose.yml:

```
#docker-compose

version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context:  ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    links:
      - app
    restart: always
    environment:
      DOMAINS: 'ns2.wechoose.ro -> http://app:5000'
      STAGE: 'production'
```

Nginx is not yet installed, I tried installing it but it failed probably because I didn't do the configuration right.

The Nginx configuration file I used before, which failed was like this:

Nginx:

```
server {

    server_name ns2.wechoose.ro  www.ns2.wechoose.ro;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as your docker-compose configuration, or your nginx configuration files? Please do this by editing your original post.

Comment: If I may ask, why haven't you installed nginx and edited the configuration file? I haven't worked with Docker on DO but I have set up a nginx reverse proxy on DO and I suspect this tutorial is what you're looking for: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-host-multiple-docker-containers-on-a-single-droplet-with-nginx-reverse-proxy